# How to join 2 table with time range

Tags: mysql, datetime, join

I have two tables, for example:

Table 1 - Transaction

```
TransID | User       | Date
1       | Andrew     | 2015-06-16 13:13:00
2       | Andrew     | 2015-06-16 14:15:00
```

Table 2 - Discount

```
DiscountID  | User       | Date                | Discount
1           | Andrew     | 2015-06-16 13:00:00 | 30
2           | Andrew     | 2015-06-16 14:00:00 | 25
```

I want to join that table into 1 output:

```
User     | Date                | Discount
Andrew   | 2015-06-16 13:13:00 | 30
Andrew   | 2015-06-16 14:15:00 | 25
```

Please help me for this problem, I'm already frustrated.

Comment: Learn [**JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in sql

Comment: but the date have a different hour information.

Comment: @Soepenong: The required result shows that you need 3 columns from Transaction table and Discount column from Discount table. Looks like a simple join. If it is not what you want, please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: @RagingBull i can't edit my question, i'm already post my new question. please check :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866690/how-to-set-value-according-to-time-frame-from-another-table