# How to set value according to time frame from another table

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, join

i have two tables, for example :

Table 1 - Transaction

```
TransID | User   | Date 
1       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:13:00 
2       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:15:00
3       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:17:00
4       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:15:00
5       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:18:00
6       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:25:00
7       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:35:00
8       | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:55:00

Table 2 - DISCOUNT 

DiscountID | User | Date | DISCOUNT <br>
1 | Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:00:00 | 30 <br>
2 | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:00:00 | 25<br>
2 | Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:30:00 | 20<br>
```

I want to apply the 'Discount' according to the time frame in 'Table 2', and become like this below.

Table outcome

```
User | Date | Discount
Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:13:00 | 30
Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:15:00 | 30
Andrew | 2015-06-16 13:17:00 | 30
Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:15:00 | 25 
Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:18:00 | 25
Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:25:00 | 25 
Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:35:00 | 20
Andrew | 2015-06-16 14:55:00 | 20
```

Comment: explain how discount is counting..

Comment: i have a fiture to input discount information into database, and the date on discount table is the date when i input discount information.